# Elide versus omit

Tags: meaning, synonyms, semantics

Do "elide" and "omit" mean exactly the same thing?  Are they completely interchangeable?  Or is there some nuance that would indicate that you should use one over the other depending on the circumstance?

Comment: This is a good topic for a question, roryap. If you add some research, it should not be closed for 'lack of research // general reference'. I'm sure that 'a single link to a single reference work will give the answer here' is extremely far from the truth. Sadly, I'm also prepared to bet that different groups of linguists have their own conflicting definitions of 'elide'.

Answer (score 6):

*Omit* can be and is used in many contexts where *elide* would be at best an odd choice. Notable among these is where what is being negated is an *action,* which one *omits* (fails) to perform. *Elide* applies more narrowly to the use of *language,* as when a syllable or vowel is elided in pronunciation, or some potential subject matter is passed over in silence. OED s.v. *elide,* only defs. not marked as obsolete:

> 2. To strike out, suppress, pass over in silence. [though examples given clearly instantiate only this last]
> 3. *Grammar.* To omit (a vowel, or syllable) in pronunciation.

Comment: RHK Websters disagrees: 1. to omit (a vowel, consonant, or syllable) in pronunciation.
2. to abridge.
3. to delete (a written word or passage).
4. to ignore; pass over.